# "&" operator is not defined for string select from .. and type datarowview

Tags: sql, vb.net

i tried retrieving data from database to textboxes and comboboxes but i get "&" operator is not defined for select from .. and datagridview
it only works without the and sql statement

```
  Private Sub getData()
        con.Open()
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        Dim Mycommand As New SqlCommand("SELECT Mathematics,English,Integrated_Science,Social_Studies,French,RME,Creative_Arts,ICT  from exams  where student_ID ='" & stud_id.Text & "' AND student_class='" & stud_class.SelectedItem & "' AND term='" & term.SelectedItem & "' AND date_of_exams='" & date_paid.Value & "'", con)
        Dim sqlDa As New SqlDataAdapter(Mycommand)
        sqlDa.Fill(dt)
        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            maths.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Mathematics").ToString()
            english.Text = dt.Rows(0)("English").ToString()
            science.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Integrated_Science").ToString()
            social.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Social_Studies").ToString()
            french.Text = dt.Rows(0)("French").ToString()
            rme.Text = dt.Rows(0)("RME").ToString()
            arts.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Creative_Arts").ToString()
            ict.Text = dt.Rows(0)("ICT").ToString()
        Else

        End If
        con.Close()

    End Sub
```

Comment: have you tried + instead of &

Comment: the statement works if i exclude the "AND"

Comment: Maybe use parameters for your query rather than sting concatenation.  Normally will solve many syntax errors when building sql commands

Comment: @Hursey, the OP absolutely should use parameters but it won't actually solve the issue here, because assigning the `SelectedItem` of a bound `ComboBox` to a parameter will still not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo have clearly bound a `DataTable` to your `ComboBoxes`, which means that every item is a `DataRowView`, which means that the `SelectedItem` is a `DataRowView`, hence the error message when you try to concatenate the `SelectedItem` here:

```
 "... student_class='" & stud_class.SelectedItem & "' AND term='" & term.SelectedItem & "' AND ..."
```

If you have set the `ValueMember` of the `ComboBoxes` then you should be using `SelectedValue` rather than `SelectedItem`, otherwise you should be using `Text`.

By way of further explanation, when you bind a `DataTable` to a control, the data actually comes from its `DefaultView`, which is a `DataView` object. That's what enables you to sort and filter the bound data and it's why each item is a `DataRowView` rather than a `DataRow`. If you set the `DisplayMember`, you are specifying which column's data should be displayed and exposed via the `Text` property. If you set the `ValueMember`, you are specifying which column's data should be exposed via the `SelectedValue` property. Usually, the `DisplayMember` is a name or description and the `ValueMember` is a primary key or other ID.